# How can I apply CSS transition to the same object which has to be destroyed and re-created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a `<div class="foo"></div>` which, for some reasons, is destroyed and recreated every 5 seconds in a random position.

Normally, we can use `.getElementsByClassName(...)` or whatever to select the `<div></div>` and change the position properties to move the box. When we apply `transition: all 2s;` to the class, the box has smooth moving animation, magically.

However, in my case, for some strange reasons, we have to destroy the `<div class="foo"></div>` first and then recreate again. Now, `transition: all 2s;` doesn't work because it doesn't refer to the same object.

What should I do to tell CSS to know that this box is the same as the previously-destroyed one so the transition applies properly?

---

**Note:**

- The element can be up to `n` elements, so assigning ids individually wouldn't be a great idea. Maybe, I'm wrong.
- No jQuery please

---

**Code**

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
...
<div class="foo"></div>
```

```css
.foo {
  transition: all 2s; /* I know, using `all` is not really a good idea */
}
```

Comment: you will require javascript or jquery for it Because once the element is recreated it should be registered with HTML DOM. You will have to tell dom that hey, I have added a new element, dom will do the remaining. it will apply the changes

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma JS is fine as long as it's vanilla and doesn't involve jQuery.

Comment: it will be simple vanilla script, Is it possible for you to tell how you are regenerating the DIV?

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma Actually, I'm using Leaflet but I simplify so others could refer in the future. Right now, I'm doing something like [this](https://pastebin.com/Q85i5Qkt). (Sorry, for using pastebin since formatting would be better)

Comment: my apologies, I am unaware of leaflet, if you can provide me with the link of leaflet library that might help me.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma Thank you so much! Here is the link: https://leafletjs.com/

Comment: I have got few more questions, can you join this chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197875/leaflet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197877/discussion-between-sachin-vishwakarma-and-mongolato).